# How do I use useState to attach files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, use-state

I'm trying to do this the file is attached, but it is not clear how correctly!

```
<form action="#">
                <div className="file-field input-field ">
                    <div className="btn indigo darken-1" >
                        <span>File</span>
                        <input type="file" multiple
                               onChange={e => setLesson({title:lesson.title,description: lesson.description,files:e.target.value})}>
                            </input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="file-path-wrapper ">
                        <input className="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files" style={{color: '#FFFFFF'}}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Here is the **useState**

```
    const [lesson,setLesson] = useState({
    title: '', description: '',files:{}
})
```

The ultimate goal is to send the file to the server and have a link to it, how to do it with this approach?
That is, when you click on the File button, you could attach the file to useState

Comment: So is your actual question how to send files via ajax? Or what do you mean with "attach" here?

Comment: I want to know how I can have these files inside lesson

Comment: I believe `e.target.files` is what you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#getting_information_on_selected_files . This has nothing to do with React in particular though.

Comment: Please use ``event.target.files`` not ``event.target.value``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.target.files` to achieve your goal.

Last but not the least, there are many issues with you code.

Here is the FIXING:[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sound-q2jfm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: files will comes in array so use `e.target.files[0]`. and it is fine if you use `files:{}` 
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-feynman-p6oi0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Then what is the point of using `multiple` ?